# Can Gerrit replace Trac for issue tracking and code browsing

Tags: git, jenkins, trac, gerrit

My system contains:

- Multiple `git` repositories,
- `Trac 0.12.2` for issue\feature tracking, wiki pages and code browsing (diffs etc.)
- `Jenkins` for CI, it pushes versioning changes to `git` when releasing.

I want to move to `gerrit` bexause of its code review capabilities, gate-keeper like functionality and since it works better with multiple `git` repositories.

My question is can `gerrit` replace `Trac` for the aforementioned functionality?
And how can I get Jenkins to work with it when releasing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gerrit works great for code review & access controls.  It does not have any issue tracking or wiki capabilities.  You will need to use a separate system for these features.  It is popular to tag your git commit message with an issue tracker ID, and configure Gerrit to provide links to your issue tracker when those tags are detected.

Gerrit uses gitweb for code browsing.  Gitweb isn't ideal for a few reasons, and Google is working on a replacement system which they will hopefully open-source when it are ready.

There are lots of opportunities to integrate Jenkins with Gerrit.  You can have Jenkins run test builds of code under review to make sure it won't break the build, for example.  Look at the gerrit-trigger plugin.

Comment: Isn't there any gerrit-plugin for issue tracking?

Comment: Not currently, no - but plugin capability is very new to Gerrit so nobody has had much of a chance to use them yet.  Plugins were just added with release 2.5 this week, and visual plugins which impact the Gerrit UI are not yet officially supported.